# CSS Grid - Span two columns unless the row holds only one

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

### The problem

I'm struggling to make a relatively simple CSS Grid layout truly responsive. Here's what I want to achieve:

1. Layout an image next to some text with a 1/3 - 2/3 split, i.e. the image takes one third of the available space, the text two thirds.
2. Limit the minimum width of the image and the text to a fixed value (like 15rem).
3. Have the text automtically wrap to the next row if the available space goes below the threshold where it fits next to the image (based on the minimum widths and and the column gaps).

Important constraint: I want the layout to wrap based on container widths, not on viewport widths, so **using media queries is not an option**.

### My attempts

The 1/1 - 2/3 split is simple:
`grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr`

But that approach doesn't allow for a minimum column width, so this needs to be modified using the [RAM approach](https://web.dev/one-line-layouts/#07.-ram-(repeat-auto-minmax):-grid-template-columns(auto-fit-minmax(lessbasegreater-1fr))), so we can fit as many columns as we want:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr));`

Then we can simply tell the image to span one column, the text to span two columns:

```
.one-column {
    grid-column: span 1;
}
.two-columns {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Now here's the problem: `span 2` will create a zero-width implicit column on small container sizes when there is only space for one column, resulting in a broken layout, the text being wider than the image by the width of the column gap. As far as I can tell, telling the text to `span 2` only if two explicit columns are available is not possible.

Here's a codepen with the problem:

https://codepen.io/MoritzLost/pen/NWRZNgz

I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a truly responsive solution to this relatively simple layout. All the examples for responsive grids that I found online don't seem to take into account grids with uneven column-spans, or if they do they use media queries to fix the resulting problem. Is there a way the above example can be fixed? Or is there a better approach to achieve the desired layout **without** using media queries? Thanks!

Comment: that's what mediaquerie is made for IMHO. but flex could help https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGwPeMb

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Mediaqueries don't work since I want to place this component in a container which may have a different size from the viewport (for example, in a sidebar on a desktop it may still need to wrap around). But flex is a great idea here, thanks! I guess I was to fixated on using grid. Though I'm still surprised that there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in grid, so if someone has a solution using grid I'd appreciate that as well. Another thing to note is that column-gap for flex isn't universally supported (yet): https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap

Comment: *Though I'm still surprised that there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in grid* --> there is no suprise, what you are describing is not a *grid*, as simple as that. Flexbox is the way to go here. Trying to force this using CSS grid will either give you headaches or a very hacky code

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, what about _any_ other layout where I want to span two columns? I don't see a way to make `span` responsive in the sense that if the container gets small enough, the grid will wrap to a single-column layout. Which is kind of a requirement for every modern grid layout. So I don't feel like this is such an edge-case ...